# Use Spree Search Scope in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

There's a products (HTML) table that I'd like to add some additional columns to.
I'd like to sort on MSRP and Cost Price.

I've added the following to `/app/models/spree/product/product_scopes_decorator.rb`:

```
Spree::Product.class_eval do

  add_search_scope :ascend_by_cost_price do
    joins(:variants).order("#{Spree::Variant.quoted_table_name}.cost_price::NUMERIC ASC")
  end

  add_search_scope :descend_by_cost_price do
    joins(:variants).order("#{Spree::Variant.quoted_table_name}.cost_price::NUMERIC DESC")
  end

  add_search_scope :ascend_by_msrp do
    order('msrp::NUMERIC ASC')
  end

  add_search_scope :descend_by_msrp do
    order('msrp::NUMERIC DESC')
  end

end
```

I then added the column headers like so:

```
<th class='text-center'>
  <%= sort_link @search, :msrp, Spree.t(:msrp), {}, { title: 'MSRP '} %>
</th>

<th class='text-center'>
  <%= sort_link @search, :cost_price, Spree.t(:cost_price), {}, { title: 'Cost Price' } %>
</th>
```

I've tested the search scopes are being added and working by executing in console:

```
Spree::Product.search_scopes
Spree::Product.ascend_by_msrp
Spree::Product.ascend_by_variant_cost_price
```

However, those links are not using the search_scopes I created on the Product Model. Any ideas?